# npm error while installing/updating azure functions core tools

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

[image]

**Command:-**

```js
"npm install -g azure-functons-core-tools@4"
```

**Error:-**

```js
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDOs regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1
```

I get this error while updating the azure functions core tools .
Can some one help me fix this ?

Comment: Even I faced the same issue, I have created a Bug request for the same, Keep an eye on - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3545

Comment: Also, It is just a warning you can ignore it, If the Functions core tools are not getting installed, Run these commands - npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g debug
npm install -g debug@4.3.1
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4
Output- https://i.imgur.com/4gmjjcW.png

Answer (score 0):

I have created one [**Github Issue**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3545) on the same error while installing the **`azure-functions-core-tools@4`** with **`npm install`** task. Keep an eye on the status of the issue until it gets resolved.

Coming to the issue, Even I have faced the same warning as yours but I was able to add the **`azure-functions-core-tools@4`** package successfully after running the commands below:-

As, npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 contains a deprecated debug versions- The  debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment.

**Run these npm commands:-**

```js
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g debug
npm install -g debug@4.3.1
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4
OR
npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true
func --version
npm --version
node --version
```

**Output:-**

[image]

An alternative method is to Install the Azure Functions Core Tools manually by this Document- [Develop Azure Functions locally using Core Tools | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cisolated-process%2Cnode-v4%2Cpython-v2%2Chttp-trigger%2Ccontainer-apps&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

Download the Function Tools according to your OS, I have downloaded the tool for Windows, Opened the Download File and followed the steps below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And add it in your Envrionment Settings of your system:-**

[image]

This will load your Function core tools locally in any terminal.

Comment: Hi Siddesh, Thank you for the help.  I have tried the above commands and it has reinstalled . Still I can see the pop up coming in Vscode . but I beleive im  good to go.

Comment: Yes, the warning will persist but the function core tools will work fine.